# Get the title of toast notification in background task

Tags: windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I can trigger the background task with `ToastNotificationHistoryChangedTrigger` once we removed the toast notification from the action center,I want to get the title of closed notifications in the background task of UWP.

Answer (score 1):

It seems it's not possibile without calculating the delta between your notifications collection before and after deletion.

The API you're using was designed with wearables in mind.

> The background task is simply a shoulder tap. It does not provide any information about which specific notification was added or removed. When your background task is triggered, you should sync the notifications on your wearable so that they reflect the notifications in the platform. This ensures that if your background task fails, notifications on your wearable can still be recovered the next time your background task executes.

See [the documentation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/2016/05/26/notification-listener-documentation-windows-10/) for more informations.